# substituting xml values programmatically with scala

Tags: xml, scala

I'm writing a tool to update some xml files (pom.xml in this case) with scala because the effort it would take in java is significantly higher than (in theory) it is with scala. I can parse the xml file just fine, but I need to replace nodes in the existing xml and rewrite the result. for example:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>foo</groupId>
    <artifactId>bar</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

So I want to find all nodes like this and replace them with:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>foo</groupId>
    <artifactId>bar</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version> <!-- notice the lack of -SNAPSHOT here -->
</dependency>
```

So, I can get all the version nodes simply enough, but how to replace them with the node that I want?

```
// document is already defined as the head of the xml file
nodes = for (node <- document \\ "version"; if (node.text.contains("SNAPSHOT"))) yeild node
```

then I want to do something like:

```
for (node <- nodes) {
    node.text = node.text.split("-")(0)
}
```

which doesn't work because node is immutable. I looked at the copy method for a Node, but it doesn't include `text` as a parameter.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/970675/scala-modifying-nested-elements-in-xml/1306415#1306415

Comment: Some good answers here. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/a/23092226/35274

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You really should take a look at other questions on Stack Overflow about modifying XML. Look at the "Related" links to the right.

Here:

```
scala> <dependency>
     |     <groupId>foo</groupId>
     |     <artifactId>bar</artifactId>
     |     <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
     | </dependency>
res0: scala.xml.Elem =
<dependency>
    <groupId>foo</groupId>
    <artifactId>bar</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>

scala> new scala.xml.transform.RewriteRule {
     |   override def transform(n: Node): Seq[Node] = n match {
     |     case <version>{v}</version> if v.text contains "SNAPSHOT" => <version>{v.text.split("-")(0)}</version>
     |     case elem: Elem => elem copy (child = elem.child flatMap (this transform))
     |     case other => other
     |   }
     | } transform res0
res9: Seq[scala.xml.Node] =
<dependency>
    <groupId>foo</groupId>
    <artifactId>bar</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Do you have a glue what complexity in time your solution has? How costly is the match/search in the XML-tree? O(log n)?

Comment: @Themerius It used to be n squared, for depth n, if I recall correctly. There was a ticket and a patch for it, but I don't recall if it ever got fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Text is represented as a `Node` inside of the `Element`s Node.  So a bit of functional recursion will let you do a deep copy & filter:

```
def deepCopy(node:Node) : Node = node match {
  case e : Elem => e.copy(child = this.child.toSeq.map(deepCopy))
  case t : Text => new Text(t.text.split("-").head)
  case x => x
}
```

**disclaimer:** this code was not tested for errors

Answer (score 0):

Using [Scalate's Scuery CSS3 transforms](http://scalate.fusesource.org/documentation/scuery.html) and `scala.xml.Elem#copy`:

```scala
val xml =
  <dependency>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <version>2.0</version>
  </dependency>

new Transformer {
  $("dependency > version") { node =>
    node.asInstanceOf[Elem].copy(child = Text(node.text.stripSuffix("-SNAPSHOT")))
  }
}.apply(xml)
```

yields

```scala
NodeSeq(<dependency><version>1.0</version><version>2.0</version></dependency>)
```