# Modifying xml contents scala

Tags: xml, scala, scala-xml

I have a problem similar to 
[Scala - modifying nested elements in xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/970675/scala-modifying-nested-elements-in-xml?lq=1)
I have reproduced the same code in this post. 
I am trying to modify content in an element and I have to call a function to get the content. For eg.

```
object test extends App {
  val InputXml: Node =
    <root>
      <contents>
        <version>1</version>
      </contents>
    </root>

  object t1 extends RewriteRule {
    override def transform(n: Node): Seq[Node] = {
      println("transforming '" + n + "'")
      n match {
        case Elem(prefix, "version", attribs, scope, _*) =>
          Elem(prefix, "version", attribs, scope, true, Text(computeVersion()))

        case other => other
      }
    }

    def computeVersion() = {
      println("computeVersion called")
      "3.0"
    }
  }

  object rt1 extends RuleTransformer(t1)
  val res = rt1(InputXml)
  val pp = new PrettyPrinter(width = 2, step = 1)
  Console println (pp format res)
}
```

Output is :

```
transforming ' '
transforming '1'
transforming '<version>1</version>'
computeVersion called
transforming '<version>1</version>'
computeVersion called
transforming '1'
transforming '<version>1</version>'
computeVersion called
transforming '<version>1</version>'
computeVersion called
transforming '<contents> <version>3.0</version></contents>'
transforming ' '
transforming '1'
transforming '<version>1</version>'
computeVersion called
transforming '<version>1</version>'
computeVersion called
transforming '1'
transforming '<version>1</version>'
computeVersion called
transforming '<version>1</version>'
computeVersion called
transforming '<contents> <version>3.0</version></contents>'
transforming '<root><contents> <version>3.0</version></contents></root>'
<root><contents> <version>3.0</version></contents></root>
```

computeVersion() is getting called almost every time due to complexity. I would just want it to be called when the actual tag is being processed. I tried to surround it by pattern matches like searching for `<version>` which is really not working out.
Any suggestions ?

Comment: Could you give a little more detail and perhaps explain what error you are receiving.

Comment: I have updated the question.

Comment: I've had a look and find it quite confusing. Something to do with the way RewriteRule and transform work, but haven't had time to unravel it yet. Hopefully someone more knowledgeable weighs in.

Answer (score 0):

I got this fixed. This issue is addressed in https://github.com/scala/scala-xml/issues/58

Although the fix is available in 2.12-M3 (as of today) version of scala, folks like me who use 2.11 version of scala can override the transform method in the class and paste the code which is

```
 def transform(ns: Seq[Node]): Seq[Node] = {
    val changed = ns flatMap transform
    if (changed.length != ns.length || (changed, ns).zipped.exists(_ != _)) changed
else ns
}
```